# Use Word VBA to color cells in tables based on cell value

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word I have a document with multiple tables full of data. Hidden inside these cells (out of view but the data is there) is the Hex code of the color I want to shade the cells. I chose the hex value just because it's relatively short and it's a unique bit of text that won't be confused with the rest of the text in the cell.

I've found some code online to modify but I can't seem to make it work. It doesn't give any errors, just nothing happens. I feel like the problem is in searching the tables for the text value but I've spent hours on this and I think I've confused myself now!

```
Sub ColourIn()

Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oCel As Cell
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oClr As String

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
For Each oCel In oTbl.Range.Cells
Set oRng = oCel.Range
oRng.End = oRng.End - 1

If oRng = "CCFFCC" Then
oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorLightYellow
End If
If oRng = "FFFF99" Then
oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorPaleBlue
End If

Next
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Edit:

I've also tried this code wit the same result of nothing happening:

```
Sub EachCellText()

Dim oCell As Word.Cell
Dim strCellString As String

For Each oCell In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells
strCellString = Left(oCell.Range.Text, _
Len(oCell.Range.Text) - 1)

If strCellString = "CCFFFF" Then
oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorLightGreen
If strCellString = "CCFFCC" Then
oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorLightYellow
If strCellString = "FFFF99" Then
oCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorPaleBlue

End If
End If
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The Code itself works, it highlights the cell where the Hex Code is in.
Could you post a screenshot of your table, so we can see what you really mean by "hidden inside the cells" and how you did hide the data?

Comment: Here's a screenshot with an explanation: http://i.imgur.com/mxOBbNb.png Does this code move through all the cells in the document or is it maybe getting stuck somewhere. The top of the document with Date/Time etc is also a table, I'm wondering if it's getting stuck up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is getting stuck nowhere. But you are checking the whole Cell Value against the Hex code, and this will not work since "blablabla FFFFFF" is never equal to "FFFFFF". So you have to check if the Hex code is in the Cell value:

```
Sub ColourIn()

Dim oTbl As Table
Dim oCel As Cell
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oClr As String

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

    For Each oCel In oTbl.Range.Cells

        Set oRng = oCel.Range
        oRng.End = oRng.End - 1

        Dim cellvalue As String

        'check if Colorcode is in cell
        If InStr(oRng, "CCFFCC") Then

            'Set Cell color
            oCel.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorLightYellow

            'Remove Colorcode from Cell
            cellvalue = Replace(oRng, "CCFFCC", "")

            'load new value into cell
            oRng = cellvalue
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Now you just have to add all the colors you want to use (I would prefer a Select Case statement) and the code should work fine

Comment: oh wow thanks, that looks like it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: FWIW A Select Case might be a better approach than ElseIf.

Comment: Yeah, obviously. Edited my answer

Comment: Ah yeah I saw an example that used Select Case but tbh I don't fully grasp it. I know where I am with If statements at least ;)